# Launch multilple threads managed by semaphore

Tags: multithreading, powershell, semaphore

Is there any cmdlet to manage threads, ie thread semaphore?

Possibly, without install any supplementary module...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you ask? Each PowerShell commandlet already runs in a separate thread. When you create a pipeline, each commandlet processes input objects using its own thread and pushes them to the next commandlet in the pipeline. If you want to process a lot of data in parallel you can use `ForEach -Parallel`

Comment: I already use the cmdlet `Start-Job` and collect the jobs with `Get-Job -State "Running"`. My question deal with semaphore. For example, I want to submit 10 jobs but I want to run them 4 at a time.

Comment: *Why you want that at all*?  What is the actual problem you want to solve? Most likely it's already [available out of the box](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/) without using low-level primitives